# Are there any security implications of rendering arbitrary text on an Image?

Tags: php, security, fonts

I am tasked with building a font preview system.

User supplies some text, text is rendered as an image using the font the user requested. Image is delivered to user.

Are there any security implications regarding the actual rendering?
How should I validate the incoming text? do I need to?
Should I strip tags?

Ignore the issues of storing and retrieving images, I understand that much. I'm just curious if there any attacks specific to rendering text on images.

Edit: Images will be PNG's

Comment: When was the last time that a photograph of a gun actually shot anybody?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general: no. You're just creating pixels on a canvas, there's no attack vector that those pixels could exploit. (Assuming you have no weird font renderer which attempts to interpret the text as HTML, SQL or some other "active" language.)

Having said that, *font parsers* are terrifically complex things which are known to occasionally contain bugs which can and have been exploited with malicious font files. So, if you let a user upload a broken, malicious font file which triggers exploitable bugs in your font rendering library, you may be in trouble. This is easily avoided by only letting the user choose from a list of fonts that you have selected and installed.

Comment: `there's no attack vector that those pixels could exploit.` - as long as OP isn't rendering the text as an SVG, that is.

Comment: Thank you. The fonts are selected from a list supplied by the store-owner.

Comment: @Kaloyan Good point; however, that wouldn't be "pixels" then. :)

Comment: @KaloyanDoichinov Images are just PNG's for now. I'll keep the SVG issue in mind. I saw some articles regarding that.

Comment: @deceze Right, details :)